# Assist with looping through array with different url each time; then window.location.href equals different url each time through loop

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, loops

Have a question.  I don't think it is hard but tried to figure out and not sure.  Essentially what I am trying to do is a PHP loop where the "$ad_id" is different each time we go through the loop.  Then I want to have a button outputted each time where the ad_id is appended to the url dest of the button as a querystring.  The part that is failing is that when I set the url to a Js var - even though the php var is different each time through the loop, the js var (url) when the page is rendered; the js var is basically set to the value of the last time through the loop (and all the buttons displayed have that same url).  I am thinking I need to somehow have the url be in a JS Array, with the key being perhaps the ad_id; so then there truly would be a different url each time through the loop.  Here is the code where the url ends up being set to the last time through the loop: 
 - this is within the loop - so $ad_id is different value each time:

```
$url4="/dealer-view-ad/?ad_id=".$ad_id;

?>

<script>

url_4a = "<?php echo $url4; ?>";

</script>

<button class="blue button" 
onclick="window.location.href=url_4a">View</button>
```

So that is the loop...anyone have any suggestions?

********* My Solution 7:08PM EST ******************

Basically all I need to do was "echo" the PHP var into my button html...tested it and it is working; here is the code:

```
<button class="blue button" onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $url4; 
?>'">View</button>
```

Comment: Well I was able figure this out, totally different way - I will post an update in my question at bottom called "My Solution"...

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out...just need to echo the php var into my button like so:

```
<button class="blue button" onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $url4; 
?>'">View</button>
```